# How to add Form from dropdown clicked in react native?

Tags: react-native, dropdown

i'm new in react native, i want to add Form if dropdown clicked. i use ModalDropdown library. but, i'm confuse to add that. thanks

this is my code

```
const OPTION_STATUS = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];

class.....{
return(
<ModalDropdown

                  options={this.state.status_option}
                  defaultIndex={-1}
                  defaultValue={'Please select Status Update'}
                  onDropdownWillShow={this._status_willShow.bind(this)}
                  onDropdownWillHide={this._status_willHide.bind(this)}
                  onSelect={(idx, value) => this._status_onSelect(idx, value)}
                />
);

 _status_willShow() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({
      status_option: OPTION_STATUS,
    }), 2000);
  }

  _status_willHide() {
    this.setState({
      status_option: null,
    });
  }

  _status_onSelect(idx, value) {
    console.debug(`idx=${idx}, value='${value}'`);
    this.setState({status: value});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle the form in some way inside your `_status_onSelect` function.

Example:

```
_status_onSelect(idx, value) {
    console.debug(`idx=${idx}, value='${value}'`);
    this.setState({status: value, showForm: true});
}
```

And then you can add the UI elements in your render method like so:

```
{this.state.showForm ?
<View>
  // Your form content here
</View>
: null }
```